# Should I use static methods for a menu class in a employee payroll console system?

Tags: java, arrays, static

My program is a small program that has an employee class and another Menu class that is used to manipulate an array of employees in the console program. Should the methods of the Menu class be declared static?

Some examples of the methods are addEmployee, updateEmployee and showEmployees. Every employee object is stored in an Employees array, which will be used by many other methods, such as to show all employees by passing in the array.

If the methods are declared static, then all I have to do is to pass in the array into the static methods is such as

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[50];
Menu.showEmployees(Employees);
//other example methods that manipulate the array
Menu.methodX(Employees);
Menu.methodY(Employees);
Menu.methodZ(Employees);
```

However, if not static, I have in mind to have a constructor for the Menu class that would take in an employees array, after which the menu object can manipulate the array directly as its member:

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[50];
Menu menu1 = new Menu(Employees);
menu1.showEmployees();
//other example methods that manipulate the array
menu1.methodX();
menu1.methodY();
menu1.methodZ();
```

I am aware that static methods should only be used as utility methods, but sometimes static methods can be used if convenient and if the system is not going to expand. Which is the better practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A static method is useful for invoking functions on a class that don't require state.  The most venerable example of this is `Integer.parseInt`; we don't require an instance of an `Integer` to parse a `String` into an `int`.

If you find yourself passing the state repeatedly to static functions, it's a wiser move to use an instance as opposed to all-static functions/variables.  Specifically in this case, since your operations absolutely *do* depend on state, then having static functions makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

> ...some examples of the methods are addEmployee, updateEmployee and
>   showEmployees. Every employee object is stored in an Employees array,
>   which will be used by many other methods, such as to show all
>   employees by passing in the array.

Here is a general rule:

Avoid global state.

Global state makes your programs fragile, insecure, and difficult to maintain.  Global state is the anti-thesis of **encapsulation** (which describes the principle in which data is hidden inside modular, decoupled units).

Global state is primarily made up of the static instance fields of a class.  Observing the rule above, the answer to your question depends on how your data model is defined:

- **Employee data stored in static instance fields.** In this case, your static employee methods will be able to directly access and modify the static employee data.  You should not do this, however.  It is bad design.  Any code that has access to your class can access and alter employee data causing security problems, consistency problems, and maintenance problems.
- **Employee data stored in non-static instance fields.**  In this case, your static methods cannot directly access the non-static employee data.  To solve this, you can pass a reference to the instance you wish to modify as an argument to the method.  There will still be possible concurrency problems and these will need to be considered in a multithreaded design.  This design has better encapsulation, should be less fragile, and more secure.

The best design would be to carefully construct a domain object model.  Your goal should be to have each module encapsulate all of the state and the behavior that operates on that state.  In this way, you should find that your goals can be accomplished without as many static methods.  As a benefit, your program will contain modules that are decoupled, can evolve independently, are easier to maintain, and are more secure.

The fact that you have a Menu class suggests that your design may be suboptimal.  A Menu has no obvious relationship to an Employee; it does not make intuituitive sense that a Menu -has an- Employee.  Your classes are probably not as decoupled as they could be.

Answer (score -2):

I think ,dear ,u should use static...bcz if u specify any method static ...u need not to create an object of the class to call the method .. U can directly call it by using (class_name.method_name) ...it saves memory that was being waste into creating an object.   Both method are right.......but I have to tell another thing that in java Menu class is a static class.  ...so u have to use static keyword to methods